# anchor linking to a comes at position of the page

Tags: javascript

I am using four tabs in a page. Each tab section content have in bottom of the page

like

```
Header - style(fixed & height)
tabs(4) - tabTitle

tabContant1
tabContant2
tabContant3
tabContant4
```

Each tab defined by id, When i click the tabTitle, it goes to appropriate content section in same page.

Problem is,

for example, When i click the tabTitle2, tab2Conetent comes to page top that is in page header.
at the same time, i have page header as fixed so tab2Content hide some part behind the header.
How to contents comes to below the fixed header

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to define where exactly to go in the page, here's an example of how to make that work for you:

[jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Or if you want to use just HTML, you can place an in-document anchor, such as this:

```
<div>
    <a name="MyStopOne"></a>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:20px;">
    My Content Part One
</div>
```

Then simply link to it using HTML, as such:

```
<a href="#MyStopOne">Jump to Stop One</a>
```

Notice the style="margin-top", which gives you a way to pad your spacing between where you are jumping to and where your actual content is, overcoming the problem with the static header hiding a portion of your content upon jump.

Comment: I dont want use margin because page header height is 300px so it is large. There is another option?

Comment: Write some script to give you ultimate control, hence the first option I gave in my answer.

Comment: Take a look at how I utilized the jQuery scrollTo function to gain maximum control, as well as fluidity, in how in-document linking worked:

http://vps-net.com/w3c.htm?st=TR/html-design-principles/